# How can I copy all users .bash_history files into my home directory?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

I am running as root. I want to copy all the users on the system's .bash_history files into my home directory. I can do this to combine all of them into one, but then I can't tell who's commands are who's.

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 2 -iname ".bash_history" -type f -exec cat {} >> ~/combined.txt \;
```

I would like to either put the user names between each of the files in the `combined.txt` file, or I would like to copy the files in this type of structure:

```
~/user-bash/john.txt
~/user-bash/mary.txt
~/user-bash/bob.txt
~/user-bash/larry.txt
~/user-bash/root.txt
```

How can I accomplish either one (or both) of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In zsh, using [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```
autoload zmv; alias zcp='zmv -C'  # this can go into your .zshrc
zcp '/home/(*)/.bash_history' '~/user-bash/$1.txt'
```

In other shells:

```
for x in /home/*/.bash_history; do
  u=${x%/*}; u=${u##*/}
  cp "$x" ~/user-bash/"$u.txt"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all files into one by feeding two commands into `find`: output first the file name (or a preprocessed version thereof) and then the contents:

```
find /home/ -maxdepth 2 -iname ".bash_history" -type f \
     -exec sh -c "echo {} >> combined.txt && cat {} >> combined.txt" \;
```